# Enumerate some extreme points near optimum solution

Tags: c++, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am looking for a simple way to obtain a lot of "good" solutions in a LP problem (not MIP) with CPLEX, and not only (one of the) optimal basic solution(s). By "good" solutions I mean that the corresponding objective values are not so far from the real optimal value. Such pool of solutions could help the decision-maker...

More precisely, given a certain polyedron Ax<=b with x>=0 and an objective function z=cx I want to maximize, after running the LP, I can obtain the optimal value z*. Then I want to enumerate all the extreme points of the polyhedron given by the set of constraints

```
Ax <= b
cx >= z* - epsilon
x  >= 0
```

when epsilon is a given tolerance.

I know that CPLEX offers way to generate solution pool (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.2.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX593.html)), but it will not function because this method is for MIP : it enumerates all the solutions of an IP (or one solution for every given set of fixed integer variables if the problem is a MIP).

An interesting efficient way is to visit the adjacent solutions of the optimal basic solution, i.e. all the adjacent extreme points : if I suppose the polyhedron is not degenerative, for each pair of basic variable x_B and non-basic variable x_N, I compute the basic solution obtained when x_B leaves the basis and x_N enters in the basis. Then I throw the solutions with cx < z*-epsilon, and for the others I repeat the procedure. [I know that I could improve this algorithm, but this is the general idea].

The [routine CPPXpivot](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.4.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/html/functions/CPXXpivot.html) of the Callable Library could help to do this pivoting operation, but I did not find an equivalent in the C++ API (concert technology). Does someone know if such an equivalent exist, or could propose me an other way to answer my original problem ?

Thanks a lot :) !

Rémi L.

Comment: Maybe you could try using the shadow prices (which I think CPLEX returns) of the constraints to move towards a different solution close the the globally optimal one?

Comment: Yes, the shadow prices and marginal values can be used  to do the pivoting operation. But I have to extract all the marginal rates of substitution of the final simplex table, and then do the pivot on my own... In fact I hope there exists a simplest method in the Concert technology, like CPXXpivot, which do the pivot automatically by exchanging two basic and non-basic variables...

Comment: I am not an expert on this subject, but this [thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1ae0bd1b-2a1a-48cd-af18-f0f86bcbf3fb&ps=25) on the IBM developerWorks forum sounds similar (if not the same).

Comment: @Remi L. Unfortunately that's the only way I can think of, hope someone else knows a simple solution :/

Comment: CPXXpivot is not directly accessible via the C++ API (i.e., you would have to use the C Callable Library to access that functionality).

Comment: @rkersh The first topic deals with the CPXXpivot, it is precisely here I discovered the existence of CPXXpivot, but I did not find equivalent in Concert... The other topics dealed with the degenerative solution with multiple optimal extreme points, wich is not exactly what I want to do.


Is it possible to use Callable Library routine in Concert Technology in a C++ program ?

Answer (score 1):

There is one interesting way to make this suitable for use with the Cplex solution pool. Use binary variables to encode the current basis, e.g. `basis[k] = 0` meaning nonbasic and `basis[k] = 1` indicating variable (or row) k is basic. Of course we have `sum(k, basis[k]) = m` (number of rows). Finally we have `x[k] <= basis[k] * upperbound[k]` (i.e. if nonbasic then zero -- assuming positive variables). When we add this to the LP model we end up with a MIP and can enumerate (all or some, optimal or near optimal) bases using the Cplex solution pool. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html) and [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions-using.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the two links ! It seems to be an efficient way to poupulate all the basis solutions. I think that the algorithm described here can be improved :
– by using the Dual Simplex algorithm after adding a cut and giing CPLEX the Incumbent (not feasible) ssolution we just cut, in order to accelerate the branch&cut.
– by treating the case of degenerative basic solutions, by adding some other cuts or automatically filter the solution after compute it.

Comment: I believe this is not needed when using the solution pool That will give much better performance than this kind of tinkering..